# Avoid IO operations if key has been seen

Tags: haskell

I have a Haskell program which walks files and performs an SHA1 hash to later detect identical contents of different files.  The crucial function is:

```hs
-- The logic of processing files
getFinfo :: FilePath -> IO Finfo
getFinfo path = do
    fstat <- getFileStatus path
    let inode = fileID fstat
    abspath <- absolutize path
    size <- getFileSize abspath
    content <- Bytes.readFile abspath  -- TODO: expensive IO
    let sha1 = hashWith SHA1 content   -- TODO: expensive computation
    let finfo = Finfo abspath size sha1 inode
    return finfo
```

The `Finfo` data type has just those members suggested:

```hs
-- File-info record
data Finfo = Finfo {
    fname :: String,
    f_size :: Integer,   -- size of file
    sha1 :: Digest SHA1, -- fingerprint
    inode :: CIno        -- inode on disk
    } deriving (Show, Eq)
```

Reading the content and performing the hash is expensive and unnecessary if a different name with the same inode has already been read and hashed.  It would make sense that referential transparency should (somehow) be able to avoid this in a function from `CIno`.

I'm not sure how to make that work though (Haskell newbie still; I'm trying).  I feel like if I had a function along the lines of this, it should be able to shortcut the IO:

```hs
cachingHash :: CIno -> String -> IO (Digest SHA1)
cachingHash inode fname = ...
```

Of course, I know that won't really work, because referential transparency applies to all the arguments, not only to `inode`.  I guess maybe there is a way to make a function with pattern guards that branch to two curried functions (i.e. of only `fname`).  It's murky to me.

FWIW, this self-education project is at https://github.com/DavidMertz/LanguagePractice/tree/3869684ab5bd21c1d9e8a70d870c6a8e16080d3a (or the latest version might have fixes).

Comment: This is probably a good use of the `StateT` monad transformer. Essentially, you'll change your function type to `FilePath -> StateT HashCache IO Finfo`, where `HashCache` is something like `Map CIno (Digest SHA1)`. Inside the function, you can then use `gets` and `modify` to retrieve a precomputed hash or add a newly computed hash to the state as necessary. In the end, you would use `runStateT foo empty`, where `foo` is whatever combination of calls to `getFinfo` you put together.

Comment: Also, since you're already working in `IO`, you could exploit the mutability and use `ReaderT (IOHashTable .. CIno (Digest SHA1)) IO Finfo`. The mutable hash tables in the `hashtables` package can only be used in IO, but provide constant lookup complexity instead of amortized constant (like in immutable `HashMap`) or logarithmic (like in immutable `Map`).

Comment: This is a bummer.  `hashtables` seems to choke on Digests, which it believes are not hasheable.  And `cryptonite` seems falsely to claim that digests are byeteable, but they choke on `toBytes`. No instance for (hashable-1.3.2.0:Data.Hashable.Class.Hashable
CIno)
        do content <- Bytes.readFile abspath
           let sha1 = hashWith SHA1 content
           byInode <- H.new
           H.insert byInode inode sha1

Comment: Maybe try memoizing approach? https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-memo

Comment: @arrowd I think that just kicks the can down the road.  Reading the (somewhat thin) documentation on monad-memo, it seems like I'll have the same problem I already do. Namely, I cannot memoize on all the arguments for my need, I need to memoize on just one of them.

I need to pass **both** an inode and a filepath.  But **only** when the inode value has been processed before, I need to ignore the filepath and do a cheap lookup.

Comment: If you did have such a `cachingHash` function, supposed that you computed the hash, which would then be cached, then the file contents changes, then later you retrieve the cached hash value, would your program then not (mistakenly) conclude that the file had not changed?

Comment: Sure, a long-lasting cache could be invalidated if file contents change.  But that's sort of orthogonal to the purpose of my program.  Let's say I have fileA, fileB, and fileC which are filenames for inodes 1, 1, 2.  If I first hash fileA, I don't want to do the work of hashing fileB (the same inode).  But whether or not I do it, the contents of fileA/inode=1 might have changed by the time I get to fileB... and hence my map of {filename->hash} would be invalid either way.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved my narrow problem. But I'd still like to understand my actual question.  Rather than caching/memoizing the expensive I/O and computation of a (SHA1) hash, I just put it off.  For my specific application, this is actually better; however, if I actually wanted to do **other things** with the `[Finfo]` list, this would not work.

I changed the data type to exclude the sha1 record:

```hs
-- File-info record
data Finfo = Finfo {
    fname :: String,
    f_size :: Integer,   -- size of file
    --sha1 :: Digest SHA1, -- fingerprint
    inode :: CIno        -- inode on disk
    } deriving (Show, Eq)
```

Then when I process the `[Finfo]` collection, I perform hashing on an "as needed" basis.  In this approach I also create a unique "pseudo-hash" when there is only one inode in the list to avoid the expense (because the hash is just a technique to find duplicate contents, not the goal in itself).

```hs
type ByInode = Map (CIno) [Finfo]  -- groupByInode does obvious thing

-- Print report on specific file size (if any dups)
printSizeRecord :: (Integer, [Finfo]) -> IO ()
printSizeRecord (size, finfos)
    | size > 0 && length finfos > 1 = do
      let byInode = groupByInode finfos
      -- There are multiple filenames of `size` but just one inode
      if (length byInode) == 1 then do
          let ino = inode $ head finfos
          putStrLn $ "Size " ++ show size ++ " | SHA1: <INODE " ++ show ino ++ ">"
          for_ [fname finfo | finfo <- finfos] (\fname -> do
              putStrLn $ "  " ++ fname )
      else do
          let byInode = groupByInode finfos
          -- `sha1s` is just a list of hashes; need to match with byInode
          -- Each one pertains to one more filenames with same inode
          hashes <- forM (Map.assocs byInode) (\(inode, finfos) -> do
              return (getHash (fname $ head finfos)) )
          sha1s <- forM hashes (\hash -> liftIO hash)
          -- Report iff there are duplicate hashes among these
          printSizeMultiInodes size byInode sha1s
    | otherwise = do
      return ()
```

I actually have not yet quite got `printSizeMultiInodes` worked out.  But that is some variation on zipping and walking my two data structures (a Map and a List), and not in itself as inherently confusing.